# Как делать свайпы в Content из Scroll View?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

[image: Content поле]

[image: Иерархия]

Есть вот такие панели в Content из Viewport на Scroll View.

Они должны скролится вертикально в любой точке экране а также каждая панель когда к ней прикасаешься должна свайпатся в вправо ( только в одну сторону ) и удаляться из Content. Как на телефоне в Галерее, слайдишь фотки и слайдом вверх удаляешь их из галерее. Мне нужна эта функция, как её реализовать?

Как это реализовать? Я пробывал делать Scroll View который будет присвоен каждой панели и свайпать уже в каждый в своем контенте находясь в одном большой контенте но проблема в том что я не смог крутить уже вниз потому что поставил скролы в горизонталь и каждый теперь скролиться только влево вправо, кто поможет решить эту задачу, долго пытаюсь решить, столько видео и все говорят только про скролы но никто как свайпать от туда и удалять

Comment: Свайп вправо после просто нажатия или же пальцем(курсором) вести впарво?

Comment: Пальцем вести желательно, и вести поле краю и "выбросить"